# Python - How to use map function and lambda function with if condition

Tags: python, dictionary, if-statement, lambda

I want to compare the wordlist and the checklist by using map function and lambda function
if the words in wordlist and checklist. this words will be deleted in wordlist.
Anyone can help me? thanks a lot

```
wordlist = ['hello','world','Tom']
checklist = ['hello','world']

print('before')
print(wordlist)

list(map(lambda x: wordlist.remove(x) if x in checklist else None ,wordlist))
print('after')
print(wordlist)
```

Current Result:
before
['hello', 'world', 'Tom']
after
['world', 'Tom']

Expected result:
before
['hello', 'world', 'Tom']
after
['Tom']

Comment: One should never remove items from a list while iterating over it.

Comment: @bereal is right. It is better to add all not matching strings to a new list: 
`new_lsit = [x for x in wordlist if x not in checklist]`

Answer (score 2):

`map` always produces one output item for each input item, it can not *remove* elements. Furthermore, `map` *should not be used to mutate objects*, that's not its job, and because it's lazy the results can be unexpected.

`filter` is designed to create an output with less elements than the input, although it's mostly useful if you already have a ready-made predicate (filtering) function.

Since you do not, you can and should use [comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#displays-for-lists-sets-and-dictionaries) which provide a relatively terse way to perform iteration, filtering, mapping and collection in a single construct:

```py
wordlist = ['hello','world','Tom']
checklist = ['hello','world']

print('before')
print(wordlist)

wordlist = [word for word in wordlist if word not in checklist]
print('after')
print(wordlist)
```

ps: if you want to modify things in-place, use a regular loop

Comment: that's is map function limitation. Thanks a lot

Comment: "Limitation" is the wrong term, it indicates a defficiency. A bear being unable to fly is not a "limitation" it's just not part of the bear's bear-ishness. And in the same way `map` has a very specific job and filtering stuff is not part of that job.

Comment: you are right. i just eager to know what map function can do and what it cannot do.
Actually, removing the word from list is not my goal. I want to apply a object function on all the elements by iteration. I want to solve it in one line

Answer (score 1):

You can try this instead, which doesn't use `lambda` but accomplishes your goal. Let us know if you absolutely must use `lambda`. The issue with your lambda expression is that your modifying the list that you are providing to map in the lambda function.

```py
wordlist_2 [word for word in wordlist if word not in checklist and word]
```

The last `and word` is to not add `None` to your list.

Comment: understood now ! Thanks a lot
I am practicing to use map function and lambda function.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you're removing elements from `wordlist` while iterating over it, which interferes with the iteration.  But `map` is the wrong thing to use for this.

The closest solution to what you're doing now uses `filter`:

```
x = list(filter(lambda x: x not in checklist, wordlist))
```

This returns a filter object which is then converted to a list.

It's probably better to just use a list comprehension:

```
y = [x for x in wordlist if x not in checklist]
```

These both produce the same result.

Note that if `checklist` is large, it would be more efficient to create a set first, then check for membership in the set, e.g. `checkset = set(checklist)`, then `x not in checkset`.  Functionally it's the same, but the set is more efficient if `checklist` is large.